# Cursor returns null when fetching data from Mediastore query in android

Tags: android, file, mediastore

I want to fetch file data from specific folder using MediaStore Query but returned cursor result is always null.

I have tried using MediaStore query

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myplayer/");
if (file.isDirectory())
{
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE, MediaStore.Video.Media.ALBUM 
        };
        String selection = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + " like?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myplayer/"};
        Cursor cursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);

        if ((cursor != null))
        {
            Log.d("trace cursor", "not null");
            Log.d("trace count", "" + cursor.getCount());
        }
  }
```

According to following code, the count of cursor is always 0, but there are some video files in myplayer directory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the selection arguments. Append the ‘**%**’ character at the end, so it is as **“myplayer/%”**:

```
new String[]{Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myplayer/%"};
```

This means to select anything that starts with the prefixed path, and has any string after “myplayer/”, which in this case are the file names.

Said that, consider that both the [DATA](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html#DATA) field, and [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()) have been deprecated in Android Q (API 29). Hence, they will not work as expected in such version, and you should already try to find alternatives if you want your code to work in future Android versions, for example to use the **BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME** instead.